# Accessing properties by name in array

Tags: swift

If I have the following setup:

```
struct Job {
    let jobDescription: String
    let days: [String]
    let hourlyPay: Double
}

var jobArray = [
    Job(jobDescription: "Dog Walker", days:  ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], hourlyPay: 7),
    Job(jobDescription: "Babysitter", days:  ["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], hourlyPay: 15),
    // etc
]
```

Or just an array (without the struct):

```
var jobArray = [
        ("Dog Walker", ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], "7"),
        ("Babysitter", ["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], "15"),
        ("Leaves Raker", ["Sunday", ""], "10")
        ]
```

If I know the job description, is there any way for me to refer to the other properties connected to it without having to go through a loop testing each job description to see if it matches?

So, instead of:

```
for (name, days, salary) in jobArray {
  if name == "Babysitter" {
     print(salary)
  }
}
```

I know which name I want from the outset and can refer to its salary without the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `Array`, I assume that you can use `Dictionary` as well.

```
var jobs = [
  "Dog Walker"    : (["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], 7),
  "Babysitter"    : (["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], 15),
  "Leaves Raker"  : (["Sunday", ""], 10)
]

if let (days, rate) = jobs["Babysitter"] {
  println("Babysitter hourly rate \(rate) on \(days)")
}
```

It prints *Babysitter hourly rate 15 on [Tuesday, Wednesday]*.

If you're interested in Swift 2 as well, you can transform the code to something like this:

```
var jobs = [
  "Dog Walker"    : (["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], 7),
  "Babysitter"    : (["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], 15),
  "Leaves Raker"  : (["Sunday", ""], 10)
]

func printJobDescription(job: String) {
  guard let (days, rate) = jobs[job] else {
    return
  }

  print("\(job) hourly rate \(rate) on \(days)")
}

printJobDescription("Babysitter")
```